# Embedding python into C++ program

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I was following [this](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) tutorial from official python documentation site, but found its examples quite simplistic, so I've built my own wrapper.
It does what I intend it to do, but I wonder if this code is good or how it can be improved.

**app.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <Python.h>


class App {
public:
  App();
  ~App();

  void Run();

private:
  static const std::string PY_CLASS_NAME;
  static const std::string PY_MODULE_NAME;

  static std::string _GetString(PyObject* obj);

  PyObject* _counter;
};
```

**app.cc**

```
#include "app.h"

const std::string App::PY_CLASS_NAME = "Counter";
const std::string App::PY_MODULE_NAME = "lib";

App::App() {
  Py_SetProgramName(Py_DecodeLocale("App", NULL));
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
  PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");

  PyObject* name = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(PY_MODULE_NAME.data());
  PyObject* module = PyImport_Import(name);

  PyObject* consturctor = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, PY_CLASS_NAME.data());
  _counter = PyObject_CallObject(consturctor, NULL);
  std::cout << _GetString(_counter) << "\n";

  Py_XDECREF(consturctor);
  Py_XDECREF(module);
  Py_XDECREF(name);
}

App::~App() {
  Py_Finalize();
}

void App::Run() {
  PyObject* res;
  for (auto i=0; i<10; i++) {
    PyObject_CallMethod(_counter, "Inc", NULL);
    res = PyObject_CallMethod(_counter, "GetValue", NULL);
    std::cout << _GetString(res) << "\n"; 
  }
  PyObject_CallMethod(_counter, "Drop", NULL);
  res = PyObject_CallMethod(_counter, "GetValue", NULL);
  std::cout << _GetString(res) << "\n";
}

std::string App::_GetString(PyObject* obj) {
  PyObject* repr = PyObject_Repr(obj);
  PyObject* str = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(repr, "utf-8", "~E~");
  const char* bytes = PyBytes_AS_STRING(str);

  Py_XDECREF(repr);
  Py_XDECREF(str);
  return std::string(bytes);
}
```

**lib.py**

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._c = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Simple Counter" + str(self._c)


    def Drop(self):
        self._c = 0

    def GetValue(self):
        return str(self._c)

    def Inc(self):
        self._c += 1
```

Comment: Are those supposed to be separate files? If so make it more visible by splitting the different code parts.

Answer (score 6):

## `app.h`

```
#pragma once
```

This is not portable, and does not work as well as advertised. You should use include guards instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <Python.h>
```

One of the biggest problems currently in C++ is slow compile times. There are several things you can do to lower compile times, but one of the most important ones is to not include what you don't need to include - *especially* in headers. Obviously that won't be a problem in this small program, but it doesn't hurt to practice best practices.

This header file doesn't need *any* of these three includes.

- `<iostream>`: you don't actually use anything from the `<iostream>` in the header.
- `<string>` : you need this for `std::string`... but as I'll explain later, you don't actually need any `std::string` stuff in the header.
- `<Python.h>`: because you only use a `PyObject` *pointer* in the header, you don't actually need to include it here.

So you can remove all three of these includes from the header, and move them to `app.cc`, where they're actually needed.

```
class App {
public:
  App();
  ~App();
```

Have you heard of the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? Since your class requires you to write a destructor, that means it almost certainly requires you to write a copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator. And in fact, your class *does* need you to do these things.

Now you probably don't want your `App` class to be copyable... that doesn't really make any sense. So for the copy ops all you need is:

```
App(App const&) = delete;
App& operator=(App const&) = delete;
```

All that's left is move ops. Should your class be movable? The answer to this question is almost always "yes", unless you have very complex technical reasons why not... which you don't here.

Unfortunately, as written your class's move ops can't be defaulted. You'll have to handle moving manually. The easiest way to do that is to define `_counter` to be:

```
PyObject* _counter = nullptr;
```

And then your move ops are like:

```
App(App&& other) noexcept
{
    std::swap(_counter, other._counter);
}

App& operator=(App&& other) noexcept
{
    std::swap(_counter, other._counter);
    return *this;
}
```

But to avoid cleaning up Python multiple times, you need to add a check that `_counter` is not `nullptr` in the destructor:

```
~App()
{
    if (_counter)
        Py_Finalize();
}
```

That's all you need to make the class safe according to the rule of five.

```
static const std::string PY_CLASS_NAME;
static const std::string PY_MODULE_NAME;
```

These don't really need to be class members. They're only used in `app.cc`, and don't seem necessary anywhere else.

```
static std::string _GetString(PyObject* obj);
```

This also doesn't need to be defined in class. It's only used in `app.cc`. If you move this and the two static constants into `app.cc`, you don't need to include `<string>` in the header.

But the main problem with this function is that `_GetString` is an illegal identifier. You cannot have an identifier that starts with an underscore and a capital letter *anywhere*. The rules for identifiers are pretty complex, so when I teach I generally advise these simple rules:

1. Never start with an underscore.
2. Never use two underscores together.

(`_counter` is technically okay because it's an underscore followed by a lowercase letter, and because of its scope. But I generally advise using something like `counter_`.)

## `app.cc`

```
const std::string App::PY_CLASS_NAME = "Counter";
const std::string App::PY_MODULE_NAME = "lib";
```

Strings work here, but this is actually a job that might be better handle by string views. String views are constexpr and no-fail - ideal for constants. And the Python library supports non-null-terminated strings, partially. Instead of `PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault()` you'd use `PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefaultAndSize()`. Unfortunately, there's no equivalent for `PyObject_GetAttrString()`, so you'll need a string there. But at the very least `PY_CLASS_NAME` can be:

```
namespace {

constexpr std::string_view PY_CLASS_NAME = "Counter";

} // anonymous namespace
```

The anonymous namespace is to make sure `PY_CLASS_NAME` is only visible in `app.cc`.

On to the constructor:

```
Py_SetProgramName(Py_DecodeLocale("App", NULL));
```

This is an issue generally, but you're not doing any error checking here. `Py_DecodeLocale()` can return `nullptr` if it fails for a number of reasons. You should really check for that, and handle it - probably by throwing an exception.

There's another issue here: resource management. You're doing everything the old-fashioned C way... mostly because the Python library is a C API. Generally when you're using a C API, you should make some proper C++ RAII classes for resource management.

For example, the memory allocated by `Py_DecodeLocale()` needs to be freed by a call to `PyMem_RawFree()`... but you never do that.

The smart thing to do is to create a `PyMem_RawFree()` deleter:

```
struct pymem_rawfree_deleter
{
    auto operator()(void* p) noexcept
    {
        PyMem_RawFree(p);
    }
};
```

Then you can store the program name in a `unique_ptr`:

```
namespace {

std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[], pymem_rawfree_deleter> p_program_name;

} // anonymous namespace
```

And now the memory will no longer leak, because it will automatically be freed.

Now the code becomes something like:

```
p_program_name.reset(Py_DecodeLocale("App", nullptr));
if (!p_program_name)
    throw std::runtime_error{"failed decoding program name"};
Py_SetProgramName(p_program_name.get());
```

Also note: `NULL` is old-fashioned and problematic. Use `nullptr`.

```
Py_Initialize();
```

Another issue with the constructor is that you don't do any checking to make sure it hasn't been called multiple times. What happens if someone does?:

```
App a1;
App a2;
```

One answer is that `Py_Initialize()` will be called twice. This doesn't seem to be a problem, because calling it a second time is guaranteed to do nothing. *However*, when one of those is destroyed, it will call `Py_Finalize()`... and now if you try to do anything with the second one, who knows what will happen - probably a crash.

What you'd need to do is make sure that only a single `App` object is created at a time. You could use a static flag for that... but you kinda already have one with `p_program_name`. If `p_program_name` is not `nullptr`, it *must* have been set in the constructor, so you know a second `App` is being constructed. What you can do is test `p_program_name` first thing in the constructor, and if it is not `nullptr`, throw an exception. And then you can set it to `nullptr` in the destructor after the call to `Py_Finalize()`.

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
```

This might benefit from a raw string constant:

```
constexpr auto PY_INIT_SYS_PATH_CODE = R"~python~(

import sys

sys.path.append(".")

)~python~";

PyRun_SimpleString(PY_INIT_SYS_PATH_CODE);
```

Next up is more resource management worries:

```
PyObject* name = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(PY_MODULE_NAME.data());

// ...

Py_XDECREF(name);
```

The C++ way of doing this is to define a deleter, and use `unique_ptr`:

```
struct pyobject_deleter
{
    auto operator()(PyObject* p) noexcept
    {
        Py_XDECREF(p);
    }
};

using pyobject_ptr = std::unique_ptr<PyObject, pyobject_deleter>;

// ...

auto name = pyobject_ptr{PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(PY_MODULE_NAME.data())};
```

And there's no need for all the calls to `Py_XDECREF()`.

Once again, there's no error checking done.

```
void App::Run() {
    PyObject* res;
```

It's generally bad practice to declare variables before they're needed. Now you do this so you can reuse `res` after the loop is done, but there's no real need for this.

```
for (auto i=0; i<10; i++) {
    PyObject_CallMethod(_counter, "Inc", NULL);
    res = PyObject_CallMethod(_counter, "GetValue", NULL);
    std::cout << _GetString(res) << "\n"; 
}
```

I'm not 100% sure with the Python API, but I *believe* you are leaking a lot of stuff here. Each time you call `PyObject_CallMethod()` it's returning a `PyObject*`, whether you catch it or not. That `PyObject*` is `nullptr` on failure (which you might want to check for) but otherwise it's something you need to consider.

This would be *really* easy with the `pyobject_ptr` I showed above:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    auto r1 = pyobject_ptr{PyObject_CallMethod(_counter, "Inc", nullptr)};
    auto res = pyobject_ptr{PyObject_CallMethod(_counter, "GetValue", nullptr)};
    // should at least check res for nullptr
    std::cout << _GetString(res.get()) << '\n';
    // cleanup is automatic
}
```

And of course, all the same for the bit of code after the loop.

```
std::string App::_GetString(PyObject* obj) {
    PyObject* repr = PyObject_Repr(obj);
    PyObject* str = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(repr, "utf-8", "~E~");
    const char* bytes = PyBytes_AS_STRING(str);

    Py_XDECREF(repr);
    Py_XDECREF(str);
    return std::string(bytes);
}
```

I've already mentioned the problem with the name, but I believe this function has a more serious bug in it. You get the pointer to the string representation of `str` as `bytes`, then you decrement the reference count of `str`... which will probably destroy it. But *then* you use `bytes` again... which probably points to freed memory. Normally this would trigger a segmentation fault, but I suspect that Python is managing its memory as a pool, so the OS doesn't detect the use-after-free.

The immediate fix for this is to simply construct the string right away:

```
std::string App::_GetString(PyObject* obj) {
    PyObject* repr = PyObject_Repr(obj);
    PyObject* str = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(repr, "utf-8", "~E~");
    const char* bytes = PyBytes_AS_STRING(str);

    auto res = std::string{bytes};

    Py_XDECREF(repr);
    Py_XDECREF(str);

    return res;
}
```

This will copy the data from `bytes` right away, before it's released.

But this becomes so much simpler if you use smart pointers:

```
std::string App::_GetString(PyObject* obj) {
    // Of course, you should be doing error checking....
    auto repr = pyobject_ptr{PyObject_Repr(obj)};
    auto str = pyobject_ptr{PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(repr.get(), "utf-8", "~E~")};
    const char* bytes = PyBytes_AS_STRING(str.get());

    return std::string{bytes};
}
```

## Summary

- Try to keep headers as minimal as possible:

  - Don't include stuff that isn't necessary.
  - Try to move as much as possible into implementation files *especially* stuff that's mostly implementation details.
- Always respect the rule of zero/three/five.
- Consider reentrancy - what happens when a function is called multiple times or a class is instantiated multiple times.
- Error checking!!!
- Use RAII, even if you have to roll your own classes to do it (which you often do when working with C APIs).

And lesser points:

- Don't use `NULL`. Use `nullptr`.
- Watch out for illegal identifiers. Simple advice: don't start identifiers with an underscore.